# Slow MySQL query in Laravel, but very fast in phpMyAdmin

Tags: laravel

I have worked with one query in Laravel, i need to optimize it. At first i have such query

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select `discounts`.`id`, `discounts`.`discount` from `discounts` left join `discount_companies_criteria` on `discounts`.`id` = `discount_companies_criteria`.`discount_id` and `discount_companies_criteria`.`is_active` = 1 where `discount_companies_criteria`.`company_id` is null and `discounts`.`status` = 1 group by `discounts`.`id`")) order by discounts.discount ASC;
```

laravel debugbar shows - 579ms

in phpmyadmin this query run by  503ms

than i have refactored code and get modified query (just remove sorting)

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select `discounts`.`id`, `discounts`.`discount` from `discounts` left join `discount_companies_criteria` on `discounts`.`id` = `discount_companies_criteria`.`discount_id` and `discount_companies_criteria`.`is_active` = 1 where `discount_companies_criteria`.`company_id` is null and `discounts`.`status` = 1 group by `discounts`.`id`")) ;
```

laravel debugbar shows - 579ms

in phpmyadmin this query run by  3ms

Can somebody explain, how i can get the same speed in laravel as in phpMyadmin?

Table discounts - 1900 rows

Table discount_companies_criteria - 7500000 rows

Comment: Quick question for clarification, are you looking at the general timing on DebugBar, or the specific Query? For reference, [this page took 61 ms to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9adJ.png), but the [query was only 10ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptEVt.png)

Comment: Specific query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General tip, don't ever run query without limit "select, delete, or update", in your case use pagination**

First the following query has no limit, which obviously would have bad performance depends on the size of the data you're dealing with:

```
SELECT `discounts`.`id`,
       `discounts`.`discount`
FROM `discounts`
LEFT JOIN `discount_companies_criteria` ON `discounts`.`id` = `discount_companies_criteria`.`discount_id`
AND `discount_companies_criteria`.`is_active` = 1
WHERE `discount_companies_criteria`.`company_id` IS NULL
  AND `discounts`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `discounts`.`id`
```

The reason why this query or the other one are faster in phpMyAdmin is because phpMyAdmin by default set limit to the query.

Comment: it seems you are right. I have add LIMIT 0, 500 to phpmyadmin and got the same time as in Laravel. Thank you.